# Postgresql 9.3 on Centos 7 with custom PGDATA

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, system-administration, centos7

I am trying to set up Postgresql 9.3 server on Centos 7 (installation via yum) inside a custom directory, which in my case is an encrypted partition (/custom_container/database) that is mounted on startup. For a certain reason Postgresql does not behave like it should in the manual and makes an error on service startup.

Note: It does not want to accept the PGDATA environment variable which I set, and when running

```
su - postgres -c '/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/initdb'
```

(given that the PGDATA directory is owned by postgres:postgres) the cluster gets initialized inside the default directory /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/
The only way to change that is using

```
su - postgres -c '/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/initdb --pgdata=$PGDATA'
```

Which initializes the directory inside the custom container I am using. This is something I could not figure out, as the docs say that PGDATA variable is taken on default.

Problem: When running

```
service postgresql-9.3 start
```

I get an error with the log

```
postgresql-9.3.service - PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.3.service; disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2014-11-10 15:24:15 CET; 1s ago
Process: 2785 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgresql93-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 10 15:24:15 CentOS-70-64-minimal systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server...
Nov 10 15:24:15 CentOS-70-64-minimal postgresql93-check-db-dir[2785]: "/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/" is missing or empty.
Nov 10 15:24:15 CentOS-70-64-minimal postgresql93-check-db-dir[2785]: Use "/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgresql93-setup initdb" to initialize t...ster.
Nov 10 15:24:15 CentOS-70-64-minimal postgresql93-check-db-dir[2785]: See %{_pkgdocdir}/README.rpm-dist for more information.
Nov 10 15:24:15 CentOS-70-64-minimal systemd[1]: postgresql-9.3.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 10 15:24:15 CentOS-70-64-minimal systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 9.3 database server.
Nov 10 15:24:15 CentOS-70-64-minimal systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-9.3.service entered failed state.
```

Which means that Postgresql, even though the cluster is initialized in the new $PGDATA directory (/custom_container/database) still looks for the cluster in /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/

Did anyone experience this Postgresql behavior before? Could it be that I forgot certain configuration options or that the problem comes from Postgresql installation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try `echo $PGDATA`, is the result displaying the correct path?

Comment: yes, it shows /custom_container/database

Comment: try to use `pg_ctl -D $PGDATA start &` and see if it works

Comment: That is interesting. su - postgres -c '/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_ctl -D $PGDATA start'
server starting
[root@CentOS-70-64-minimal database]# postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory

Comment: And su - postgres -c 'echo $PGDATA'
/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data

Comment: In other words, PGDATA is not set for the user postgres, but only for the user root!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the real problem was setting the environment variables, which I got working in the following thread:
[Centos 7 environment variables for Postgres service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848495/centos-7-environment-variables-for-postgres-service)
The issue is the PGDATA variable set inside the custom /etc/systemd/system/postgresql-9.3.service which should be created from the contents of /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.3.service which uses the default PGDATA var.

Comment: nice! and works with other versions too! I wonder if alternative init method could be used to initiate database, like with `postgresql95-setup`. Not sure how these two methods exactly differ but apart from running other stuff `postgresql95-setup` runs `initdb` internally. I couldn't however figure out how to feed `-D` switch to it, like: `usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-setup initdb -D <otherdir>` raises error: `systemctl: invalid option -- 'D'`

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a custom `postgresql.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system/`, which overrides the default `PGDATA` environment variable. Your custom service file can `.include` the default postgresql service file, so you only need to add what you want to change. That way, upgrades can still modify/improve? stuff in the default service file, while your change is preserved.

This is how I just did it in Centos 7:

```sh
cat <<END >/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service
.include /lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
[Service]
Environment=PGDATA=/mnt/postgres/data ## <== SET THIS TO YOUR WANTED $PGDATA
END

systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl restart postgresql.service
```

Verify :

```
ps -ax | grep [p]ostgres
```

**Update:**

Rather than manually creating the file and adding the .include line, you can also use the systemd built-in way:

```
systemctl edit postgresql.service
```

This will open your default editor and save your changes to `/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service.d/override.conf`

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
 ## Login with postgres user
 su - postgres
 export PGDATA=/your_path/data
 pg_ctl -D $PGDATA start &
```

Comment: OK, this works after logging in and setting the variable manually. But after logging in again the PGDATA is reset. Is there a way to save it permanently?

Comment: Thanks, now I can start postgres manually. But for some reason service postgresql-9.3 start still looks for the default directory and makes the same error as before. Is there anything that needs to be set especially for postgres to run as a service?

Comment: here some good source to read: [postgresql change default data directory](http://serverfault.com/questions/273660/postgresql-change-default-data-path)

Comment: It appears the problem is the service functionality itself: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44370/how-to-make-unix-service-see-environment-variables "service strips all environment variables but TERM, PATH and LANG which is a good thing" so I need to create a custom service for the pgsql database.

Comment: ah yeah, you can modify postgresql service (backup first). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I think the most "CentOS 7 way" to do it is to copy the service file:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.6.service /etc/systemd/system/postgresql-9.6.service
```

Then edit the file */etc/systemd/system/postgresql-9.6.service*:

```
# Location of database directory
Environment=PGDATA=/mnt/volume/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/
```

Then start it `sudo systemctl start postgresql-9.6` and verify:

```
# sudo ps -ax | grep postmaster
32100 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postmaster -D /mnt/volume/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit file /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3:
PGDATA=/your/custom/path