# Centos 7 environment variables for Postgres service

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, postgresql-9.3, centos7

Recently I had the problem of starting a postgresql service with custom PGDATA path. It tried to look in the default data directory (/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/) which was not initialized and therefore triggered these errors. It appears the problem is that the service starter on Centos 7 strips all the environment variables, including PGDATA.

[Interesting thread on the issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44370/how-to-make-unix-service-see-environment-variables)

Is there a way to configure

```
service postgresql-9.3 start
```

to use custom environment variables? Are there configuration files for services where these variables have to be defined?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As that link says the general mechanism for this is that the service init file sources a file from `/etc/default/$servicename` when it runs and you can configure variables there. Does the pgsql init script do that? I don't know you'd have to look.

Comment: I only have [grub  nss  useradd] files inside the /etc/default/ directory. Do I have to make a special postgresql-9.3 script inside that directory accordingly?

Comment: You need to look at the postgresql init.d file. See if it looks for a file in the `/etc/default` directory and then create that with whatever variables/etc. you need. `grep /etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql-9.3 /default` is likely a good start.

Comment: I made changes to /etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql and it works for me. I think I took it from https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/start-scripts/linux

Comment: I created the file /etc/systemd/system/postgresql-9.3.service as it states in the comments of /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.3.service and set the PGDATA variable there. For some reason it still does not want to accept this variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I got a solution that worked for me.

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/postgresql-9.3.service
```

with the contents copied over from /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.3.service and PGDATA variable changed. Then

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

And then I started the service normally and it worked fine. The trick was making changes to this service configuration file.

Comment: not a very elegant solution, more like a hack, but it does work

Answer (score 13):

Thanks for the above answer, we just ran into this change today. You can also keep the default settings and only override the PGDATA variable by putting the following in */etc/systemd/system/postgresql-9.3.service*:

```
# Include the default config:
.include /lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.3.service

[Service]
Environment=PGDATA=<your path here>/pgsql/9.3/data
```

This removes the need to reintegrate changes in */usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.3.service* back to your local copy.

Comment: This solution is a better answer, since it keeps all changes in the original service file.

Comment: The `systemctl daemon-reload` is also needed here.

Comment: what is <your path here> represents ?

Comment: @KannanRamamoorthy It means the path to where you want the database files stored, usually a different drive so you don't run out of space.